# Which Boolean is Faster? < or <=

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, optimization, micro-optimization

I'm doing some work involving processing an insane amount of data in browser. As a result I'm trying to optimize everything down to the nuts and bolts. I don't need anyone telling me that I'm wasting my time or that premature optimization is the root of all evil.

I would just like to know if anyone that understands how JS works would know whether or not a lesser than boolean runs faster than a lesser than equals boolean. What I mean by that is, would:

```
return (i<2? 0:1)
```

Be parsed and run faster than:

```
return (i<=1? 0:1)
```

In this example we're assuming that i is an integer. Thanks.

Comment: There is most likely no difference, but you can check yourself with https://jsperf.com

Comment: JSPerf has been down for almost a year. In my tests  it seems as though just the greater than is faster, but it tends to fluctuate, so I'm not completely sure.

Comment: You should include a test case with some of your numbers, and clarify that your question isn't so much whether one is faster than the other, but *why* it's faster.

Comment: That depends on how the engine implements it. You should simply profile your code in the environment you are using.

Comment: There almost no chance that this is the best thing for you to focus on in your optimization quest, I would look at the larger structure of your program first.. Also does your app have a back-end?

Comment: *if* this code is optimised, the generated assembly code will just change from `JA`to `JAE` (in (x86) , and they use the same cycle count. 0,0000% change. I wonder how `return +(i>1)`compiles, since it seems there's no branching here...

Comment: qwwqww, It is an important thing, I'm not crazy, yet. Yes, it does have a back-end but there's no way I'm going to do any cloud computing though.

@GameAlchemist, thanks for that, you should put that as an answer.

And to everyone, thank you for your suggestions, I have realized that since it's browser based I'd probably have to adjust it for each browser, but nonetheless, this is what happens when you try to process big data in the browser.

Comment: Notice that using asm.js *might* improve performances by up to 20 times depending on browsers, worth a look for performance-frenzy people !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript standard desribes the steps that needs to be taken in order to evaluate those expressions. You can take a look at [ECMAScript 2015 Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation), section 12.9.3.

Be aware that even if there is slightly difference between steps of those two operation, other stuff in your application will have much more influence on performance that these simple operations that you cannot control in JavaScript. For example work of garbage collector, just-in-time compiler, ...

Even if you try measuring time in JavaScript, this will not work as just taking time stamps has much bigger influence on the performance than the actual expression you want to measure. Also the code that you wrote might not be the one which is really evaluated as some preoptimizations might me taken by the engine prior to actual running the code.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't call this micro-optimisation, but rather nano-optimisation.
Cases are so similar you'll most likely have a measure precision below the gain you can expect...

(Edit)
If this code is optimised, the generated assembly code will just change from JAto JAE (in (x86) , and they use the same cycle count. 0,0000% change.
If it is not, you might win one step within a `select`of the engine...

The annoying thing being that it makes you miss the larger picture : unless i'm wrong, you need a branch here, and if you're that worried about time, the statistical distribution of your input will influence WAY more the execution time. (but still not that much...)

So walk a step back and compare :

```
if (i<2) 
    return 0;
else 
    return 1;
```

and :

```
if (i>=2) 
    return 1;
else 
    return 0;
```

You see that for ( 100, 20, 10, 1, 50, 10) (1) will branch way more and for (0, 1, 0, 0, 20, 1), (2) branches more.
That will make much more difference... that might just as well be very difficult to measure !!!

(As a question left to the reader, i wonder how `return +(i>1)` compiles, and if there's a trick to avoid branching... )

(By the way i'm not against early optimisation, i even posted some advices here, if it might interest you : https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2016/04/15/writing-efficient-javascript-a-few-tips/ )

Comment: Haha, nano-optimization

Answer (score 1):

I have created a fiddle using performance.now API and console.time API's
Both the API says how much ms of the time was taken to execute the functions/loops.
I feel the major difference is the result, performance.now gives more accurate value i.e. upto 1/1000th ms.

https://jsfiddle.net/ztacgxf1/

```
function lessThan(){
    var t0 = performance.now();
    console.time("lessThan");
    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        if(i < 1000){}
    }
   console.timeEnd("lessThan");
   var t1 = performance.now();
   console.log("Perf -- >>" + (t1-t0));
}
function lessThanEq(){
    var t0 = performance.now();
    console.time("lessThanEq")
    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        if(i <= 999){}
    }
    console.timeEnd("lessThanEq");
    var t1 = performance.now();
    console.log("Perf -- >>" + (t1-t0));
}
lessThan()
lessThanEq()
```

I haven't much difference. May be iterating more may give different result.

Hope this helps you.